# UI Layout Initialization Error-The center-pane element does not exist

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I am using a Layout structure that has centerLayout, westLayout,northLayout

When i run the file, i take this following error:
"/UI Layout Initialization Error. 
The center-pane element does not exist. 
The-center pane is a required element."

my template is :

```
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" collapsible="true">
            <header>
                <div class="logo1">
                    <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/logo1.png" alt="Gestion d'accès et de habilitations" />
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><h:link outcome="/profile" value="Profile"/></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Se déconnecté</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="logo2">
                    <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/logo2.png" alt="Altijari Bank" />
                </div>
            </header>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="210" header="Menus" collapsible="true">
            <h:form id="frmMenu1">
                <p:accordionPanel multiple="true" id="acc" activeIndex="0">
                    <p:tab title="Gestion des agences">
                        <p:menu style="width:100%" id="m1">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{agenceController.prepareList()}"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{agenceController.prepareCreate()}" />                                                          
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Gestion des utilisateurs">
                        <p:menu style="width:100%"  id="m2">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{utilisateurController.prepareList()}"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{utilisateurController.prepareCreate()}" />                                
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Gestion des fonctions">
                        <p:menu style="width:100%"  id="m3">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{fonctionController.prepareList()}"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{fonctionController.prepareCreate()}" />                             
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab> 
                    <p:tab title="Gestion des applications">
                        <p:menu style="width: 100%" id="m4">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{applicationController.prepareList()}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{applicationController.prepareCreate()}"/>
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Gestion des fiches " >
                        <p:menu style="width: 100%" id="m5">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{ficheController.prepareList()}"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{ficheController.prepareCreate()}" />
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab> 
                    <p:tab title="Administration" >
                        <p:menu style="width: 100%" id="m6">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{groupeController.prepareList()}"  />
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{groupeController.prepareCreate()}" />
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Traçabilité" >
                        <p:menu style="width: 100%" id="m7">
                            <p:menuitem value="Consulter" action="#{traceController.prepareList()}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" action="#{traceController.prepareCreate()}" />
                        </p:menu>
                    </p:tab>

                </p:accordionPanel>
            </h:form>

        </p:layoutUnit>
```

I use primefaces 3.2, jsf 2.1, glassfish 3.1.2.1 
Please help me.

Comment: incidentally, as of Primefaces 6.2, the p:layout element has been deprecated, in favor of plain div elements

Answer (score 5):

As the error message suggests you are missing the center part of the layout.

**It is a required element.**

Define one similar to this:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
 YOUR CONTENT 
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: yes I specify a center layout like that:                                                           '<p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p>
                    <ui:insert name="body">Default Body</ui:insert>
                </p>
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout> '                                                                                                                     But i got the same error !!

Comment: It has to be in the same `<p:layout>` as your other content.

Comment: Yes I do that but always i got the same error !! :(

Comment: I deleted this element
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
 YOUR CONTENT 
</p:layoutUnit>

and then it worked

Answer (score 5):

This happens when there is an error in the part of the page that is inside the center pane part. This can be an invalid xhtml tag, something wrong in a bean being called or whatever. Look in your server logging an see if there is anything there.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Primefaces 6.2 and has been answered here:  [UI Layout Initialization Error PrimeFaces 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980465/ui-layout-initialization-error-primefaces-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

On primefaces 5.1 I had the case when options ware set by controler bean

```
<pe:layout id="fullPage" options="#{layoutController.layoutOptions}" stateCookie="true">
```

and in that controler I was setting child layoutPanes that ware not defined

```
// options for nested center layout
LayoutOptions childCenterOptions = new LayoutOptions();
center.setChildOptions(childCenterOptions);

// options for center-north pane
LayoutOptions centerNorth = new LayoutOptions();
centerNorth.addOption("size", "50%");
childCenterOptions.setNorthOptions(centerNorth);
```

So if you are extending primefaces showcase, be sure to disable configuration on the unexsisting panes.

Since this error is not shown on other missing panes (east, west,..) this could be a big headache to solve.